# can't call function with blank page

Tags: javascript

How to call a function in JavaScript, so that when I click in blank page then function call?

```js
function islToChr(arg) {
    d=parseInt(arg.HDay.value)
    m=parseInt(arg.HMonth.value)
    y=parseInt(arg.HYear.value)
    jd=intPart((11*y+3)/30)+354*y+30*m-intPart((m-1)/2)+d+1948440-385
    arg.JD.value=jd
    arg.wd.value=weekDay(jd%7)
}
```

Comment: you can do this function as a self invoking function expression (execute the function automatically)

Comment: `click in blank page` means?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this function as a self invoking function expression (execute the function automatically)

```
(function islToChr(arg) {
    d=parseInt(arg.HDay.value)
    m=parseInt(arg.HMonth.value)
    y=parseInt(arg.HYear.value)
    jd=intPart((11*y+3)/30)+354*y+30*m-intPart((m-1)/2)+d+1948440-385
    arg.JD.value=jd
    arg.wd.value=weekDay(jd%7)
})(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to click anywhere on the blank page and then invoke the function then try

```
function islToChr(arg) {
    d=parseInt(arg.HDay.value)
    m=parseInt(arg.HMonth.value)
    y=parseInt(arg.HYear.value)
    jd=intPart((11*y+3)/30)+354*y+30*m-intPart((m-1)/2)+d+1948440-385
    arg.JD.value=jd
    arg.wd.value=weekDay(jd%7)
}
document.onclick = function(){
   islToChr();//you can pass the argument as you wish
};
```